# Why does it say that my variable is not defined?

Tags: reactjs

Here is my react component...
I can't figure out why `nyVariable` says that it is not defined...

```
import React from "react";
import { useEffect } from "react";

const Component = () => {

  useEffect(() => {
    const myVariable = "Jim"
  }, []);

  return(<div>{myVariable}</div>) 
};

export default Component;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)

Comment: To be more specific about the code shown... The variable `myVariable` is defined *inside a function* (the callback passed to `useEffect`), so it only exists *within that function*.  But what is the purpose of `useEffect` here at all?  None.  Remove it, and just define the variable directly in the component.

Comment: Thanks, I can't believe I forgot that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A variable created inside a useEffect can not be accessed from outside the useEffect. I would recommend looking into how a useEffect and useState work.

Try something like this:

```
import React from "react";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const Component = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState("");
  useEffect(() => {
    setState("Jim");
  }, []);

  return(<div>{state}</div>) 
};

export default Component;
```

This will create a state variable that contains an empty string. Then upon the components first render, will set the state to "Jim".

Answer (score 0):

Your are getting undefined because of the scope rule in javascript. Try to do it this way.

```
import React from "react";
import { useEffect } from "react";

const Component = () => {
  const myVariable = "";

  useEffect(() => {
    myVariable = "Jim"
  }, []);

  return(<div>{myVariable}</div>) 
};

export default Component;
```

Because your defining your variable inside useEffect (Function) it is available only inside this function. you will not be able to access it outside. This is why I declared it outside first and then updated it value inside the useEffect hook.